# Output sound through jack and speakers on Samsung Galaxy phone

Tags: audio

I am trying to find a way for my phone to output sound to both the phone's jack and to the phone's speakers simultaneously.  Currently, plugging something into the jack turns off the speakers.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm hard of hearing and need the speakers so I can hold the phone up to webcaptioner.com to create automatic captions, while using the jack to plug the sound into my hearing aids.

I have a Samsung Galaxy (samsung-sgh-I747) using Android version 4.4.2.

What I have tried: I looked on the phone under "sound" and "accessibility" - nothing there works.
I also tried plugging the phone directly into the computer to see if this could make really clear captions, but the computer didn't register the incoming sound.
I tried turning on "Samsung captions" - but no captions appear anywhere.

I also found that it seems you need an app or a splitter - https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-use-your-headphones-and-speaker-at-the-same-time-for-a-mobile - I'm hoping there can be another solution.

Comment: the link you provided really says it all... there is no good way do do this. You can try an app or get a speaker, but that is your best bet. (you could also consider blutooth headphones,as this wouldnt use the internal amplifier.)

Comment: *"I'm hoping there can be another solution."* - There might be, but the simple solution is to follow the recommendation in the link you already gave. A suitable 3.5mm male-to-male [auxiliary cable](https://www.amazon.com/Stereo-1-4-inch-1-8-inch-Jack-Cables/b?ie=UTF8&node=3224439011) is about $5-$8 on Amazon and a suitable [stereo Y-spitter](https://www.amazon.com/slp/stereo-splitter/po7r4pkayqss3qq) is around the same or slightly cheaper. So you are looking at perhaps $15 for both. Not cheap, but you can just plug the auxiliary cable into the PC mic input (the Y-splitter is for the phone).

Comment: Hi Anaksunaman and ragnvaldr.js - thank you very, very much for taking the time to respond.  It's good to know what direction to go in.